# How to limit what can be submitted in an input field to an array of options?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I have the below code working okay to give users autocomplete options on a particular input field. There's one last piece I'm trying to figure out. How would I make it that the array strings are the only strings that can be submitted to the input field? In other words, if someone inputs a string that is not in the array, it would not be able to submit. Any thoughts on this are appreciated thanks.

```
//Symbol autocomplete

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var symbols1 = [
  'Bitcoin',
  'Ethereum',
  'Ripple',
  'Litecoin',
...etc...
]

autocomplete(document.getElementById("symbol-input"), symbols1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) Would be one way to check if the string provided by the user is in the array of allowed strings.

By the way, if users can select from a set of options, could you consider using a `<select>` instead of an `<input>`?